# Using Amazon's affiliate API for autocompletion with SearchIndex (Category)

Tags: autocomplete, kindle-fire

I need to have Amazon affiliate API for autocompletion work with SearchIndex (Marketplace category)

For example,
I have a site that searches for Kindle Books, and would like to have Amazon's autocompletion only return Kindle Book results.

The following URL will return all products with the keyword 'photography'

```
http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=photography
```

How can I have the above URL return only Kindle Books with keyword 'photography'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The `search-alias` query needs to be changed to `digital-text`, like so:

```
http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=digital-text&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=photography
```

You can do this for any marketplace category by changing `search-alias` to the appropriate query variable.

Here's a complete list of `search-alias` variables:

```
<select>
<option selected="selected" value="search-alias=aps">All Departments</option>
<option value="search-alias=alexa-skills">Alexa Skills</option>
<option value="search-alias=instant-video">Amazon Video</option>
<option value="search-alias=warehouse-deals">Amazon Warehouse Deals</option>
<option value="search-alias=appliances">Appliances</option>
<option value="search-alias=mobile-apps">Apps &amp; Games</option>
<option value="search-alias=arts-crafts">Arts, Crafts &amp; Sewing</option>
<option value="search-alias=automotive">Automotive Parts &amp; Accessories</option>
<option value="search-alias=baby-products">Baby</option>
<option value="search-alias=beauty">Beauty &amp; Personal Care</option>
<option value="search-alias=stripbooks">Books</option>
<option value="search-alias=popular">CDs &amp; Vinyl</option>
<option value="search-alias=mobile">Cell Phones &amp; Accessories</option>
<option value="search-alias=fashion">Clothing, Shoes &amp; Jewelry</option>
<option value="search-alias=fashion-womens">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Women</option>
<option value="search-alias=fashion-mens">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Men</option>
<option value="search-alias=fashion-girls">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Girls</option>
<option value="search-alias=fashion-boys">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Boys</option>
<option value="search-alias=fashion-baby">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Baby</option>
<option value="search-alias=collectibles">Collectibles &amp; Fine Art</option>
<option value="search-alias=computers">Computers</option>
<option value="search-alias=courses">Courses</option>
<option value="search-alias=financial">Credit and Payment Cards</option>
<option value="search-alias=digital-music">Digital Music</option>
<option value="search-alias=electronics">Electronics</option>
<option value="search-alias=gift-cards">Gift Cards</option>
<option value="search-alias=grocery">Grocery &amp; Gourmet Food</option>
<option value="search-alias=handmade">Handmade</option>
<option value="search-alias=hpc">Health, Household &amp; Baby Care</option>
<option value="search-alias=local-services">Home &amp; Business Services</option>
<option value="search-alias=garden">Home &amp; Kitchen</option>
<option value="search-alias=industrial">Industrial &amp; Scientific</option>
<option value="search-alias=digital-text">Kindle Store</option>
<option value="search-alias=fashion-luggage">Luggage &amp; Travel Gear</option>
<option value="search-alias=luxury-beauty">Luxury Beauty</option>
<option value="search-alias=magazines">Magazine Subscriptions</option>
<option value="search-alias=movies-tv">Movies &amp; TV</option>
<option value="search-alias=mi">Musical Instruments</option>
<option value="search-alias=office-products">Office Products</option>
<option value="search-alias=lawngarden">Patio, Lawn &amp; Garden</option>
<option value="search-alias=pets">Pet Supplies</option>
<option value="search-alias=pantry">Prime Pantry</option>
<option value="search-alias=software">Software</option>
<option value="search-alias=sporting">Sports &amp; Outdoors</option>
<option value="search-alias=tools">Tools &amp; Home Improvement</option>
<option value="search-alias=toys-and-games">Toys &amp; Games</option>
<option value="search-alias=vehicles">Vehicles</option>
<option value="search-alias=videogames">Video Games</option>
<option value="search-alias=wine">Wine</option>
</select>
```